# titanium android custom redirection on notification

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules, appcelerator-acs

I am developing an android application that includes gcm push notifications via ti.cloudpush module.
I would like to launch specific windows for certain type of push notifications.
Is theere any proper way to acieve this.
Following are my workouts.

```
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {
alert("Notification received: " + evt.payload);
//-------------------launch code
var win=Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:'music.js',
    exitOnClose:true,
});
```

});

i also tried by creating pending intent.It was also not failure.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the callback you'll have a payload sent back.

```
alert(evt.payload);

CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {
    Ti.API.debug(evt.payload);

}
```

The payload is a JSON string of your data payload. Use JSON.parse to turn this in to an object you can use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

You can use this payload to base the check on what intent, window or action you would like to fire.

```
var payload = JSON.parse(evt.payload);

if (payload... ) { 
    // Do first option

} else {
    // Do fallback option
}
```

Inside your callback eventEventLister from cloudPush once you have parsed the payload you could load something similar to this:

```
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {

    ... Do payload check if statement from evt.payload...

    // Or this could be a new window, alert, etc,
    Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify(0, 
        Ti.Android.createNotification({
            contentTitle : "title",
            contentText : "text",
            tickerText : "custom notification!",
            contentIntent : Titanium.Android.createPendingIntent({
                intent : Titanium.Android.createIntent({
                    url : 'foo.js'
                })
            })
        })
    );
});
```

If you want to switch out a different window, set the url object in the intent to a custom variable that is set depending on what the evt.payload is that's sent back.

eg

```
intent : Titanium.Android.createIntent({
    url : presetWindowUrl
})
```

Comment: The presetWindowUrl, can be set at the start of the function by a simple If else statement which you should be able to set your custom launch window for the intent.

Comment: do i need to specify anything in tiapp.xml file?

Comment: I've edited it to cover checking the payload sent back, with this you can write a conditional and open various windows and actions depending on the result.. Let me know if that helped or if you need anything in more detail. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.